# how to insert script tag in script code, not working for me using + ` or $

Tags: javascript, html

i have the code:

```
<div id='videoplayer'>VIDEO</div>
<script src="/js/player.js"></script>
<script>
var myfile='/videos/play/intro.mp4';

jwplayer('videoplayer').setup({
    'playlist': [{
"file": "+ myfile +",
'title': 'PLAY'
}]});
</script>
```

but not work.
i used too ${myfile}. `+myfile+`

help. 
i not know about programming, but i need that it work.

Comment: `"file": "+ myfile +",` ==> `file: myfile,`

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable `myfile`  as it is to the file property.

```
 var myfile='/videos/play/intro.mp4';
    jwplayer('videoplayer').setup({
        'playlist': [{
    "file": myfile ,
    'title': 'PLAY'
    }]});
```